# How to reload a partial view in a parent page on child page post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

The parent page contains 3 partial views in it Index_Top, Index_Left and Index_main. On hitting a button in Index_Left a new window opens using window.open("MyController/ChildPage") function in javascript.

Now I should reload only the Index_Left on the parent page on the child page submit.

Can any one help me how can I do it?

I tried using like below.
$.post("/MyController/ChildPage/", {  },
        function (result) {
            if (result.Message == "OK") {
                window.opener.location.reload(true);
                window.close();
            }
        },
        "json");

But, it is reloading the entire parent page. But, I want to reload only a Index_Left parital page.

Comment: I don't know asp.net or jquery. But I do know that you can only reload part of a page using Ajax. Is $.post an Ajax function, or a fresh-page function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the main page define a javascript function:

```
function reloadLeftPanel() {
    // Do an AJAX request and reload the left panel like for example:
    $('#leftPanel').load('<%= Url.Action("MyController", "ChildPage") %>');
}
```

And in the popup window call this function whenever you want to reload the left panel on the opener page:

```
window.opener.reloadLeftPanel();
```